# angularjs directive not working with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hello I have create an angular directive to add a bakcground and make it width equals to height(1:1) square div

```
app.directive('backImg', function($timeout){
return function(scope, element, attrs){
    $timeout(function(){
            var url = attrs.backImg;
            console.log(attrs);
            console.log("after printing attrs");
            if (url == null || url == ""){
                    url="/web/header.png";
            }
            element.css({
                    'height' :  element[0].offsetWidth,
                    'margin-bottom' : '20px',
                    'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
                    'background-size' : 'cover',
                    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                    'background-position': 'center center',
            });
    });
    };
});
```

This directive is working fine with the elements that appears when the page is first time loaded

**....SOME HTML**

```
 <div back-img="{{group.images[0].path}}"> </div> ---> Working fine
```

**....MORE HTML**

This time is not working, the only diference is that it been show if sessionSelected is true.

```
<div class="row" id="active-session" ng-show="userCtrl.sessionSelected">
    <div back-img="{{group.images[0].path}}"> </div> ---> Not working Working
</div>
```

Can you please help me figure this out, please

**EDIT**
I looks like the directive is been called while it is not showed (ng-show) and for that reason group.images[0].path is null.

how can I do to call directive when visible??. I think it will be the way

**Here you can see that the element is been populated with the correct img path when displayed**

**FIREFOX DEBUG**

```
<div back-img="/web/uploads/56f7f53a2b82bbf75033559a/nKj0DMZrVt.jpeg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are created the `<div back-img="{{group.images[0].path}}">` and use the `element[0].offsetWidth` when the element is on `display:none` css (because of the `ng-show=true` attribute). so in order for this to work you need to change the `ng-show` to `ng-if`. that way when you change the flag to true it draw the html all over again and then this will call to the `link` function in the `directive`

**EDIT**

you can always use the `$watch` function that check for update in the url and when it occurs trigger the changes

```
app.directive('backImg', function($timeout){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch(attrs.backImg,function(){
            var url = attrs.backImg;
            console.log(attrs);
            console.log("after printing attrs");
            if (url == null || url == ""){
                    url="/web/header.png";
            }
            element.css({
                    'height' :  element[0].offsetWidth,
                    'margin-bottom' : '20px',
                    'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
                    'background-size' : 'cover',
                    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                    'background-position': 'center center',
            })
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: The element actually is showed but is showed the image I have set if url is null   
if (url == null || url == ""){
                    url="/web/header.png"; <- That is the image that is been show on the div 
            }
the only thing is failling is that the div has the wrong image.

Comment: you need to see if that argument is set in the proper way. you can do it by debugging your code on that line and understand it better. it this isn't helping you can always add you code here (the controller function)

Comment: I looks like the directive is been called while it is not showed (ng-show) and for that reason group.images[0].path is null. 

how can I do to call directive when visible??

Comment: The arguments is been set when element is displayed ... se question edits

Comment: you may want to use the `$watch` function on the `attrs.backImg`

Comment: sorry for the dump question, how can I do that?.. I do not know how to use $watch... looks like it is the answer can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks it give me an error now 
Token '/' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [/web/uploads/56f7f53a2b82bbf75033559a/nKj0DMZrVt.jpeg]

How can I fix that without escaping it?

Comment: warp you url with quotes ( back-img='"/web/uploads/56f7f53a2b82bbf75033559a/nKj0DMZrVt.jpeg"')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108086/discussion-between-noel-carcases-and-zamboney).

Comment: The issue was solved by "watch" a controller variable instead of a directive atribute. Thanks